# How to dissolve the dataset on multiple conditions - R

Tags: r, filter, summarize

Consider dataset the following dataset:

| ID | Start time | End time | Traffic | Lane |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2015 | 01-02-2015 | 500 | 1 |
| 1 | 01-01-2015 | 01-02-2015 | 400 | 2 |
| 1 | 01-02-2015 | 01-03-2015 | 250 | 1 |
| 1 | 01-02-2015 | 01-03-2015 | 250 | 2 |
| 2 | 01-01-2015 | 01-02-2015 | 80 | 1 |
| 2 | 01-02-2015 | 01-03-2015 | 70 | 1 |

I want to aggregate the traffic values based on multiple conditions. The traffic values should be aggregated based on a similar `ID` and `Start` time so that the output dataset becomes:

| ID | Start time | End time | Traffic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2015 | 01-02-2015 | 900 |
| 1 | 01-02-2015 | 01-03-2015 | 500 |
| 2 | 01-01-2015 | 01-02-2015 | 80 |
| 2 | 01-02-2015 | 01-03-2015 | 70 |

What is a convenient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should achieve this by grouping `group_by()` and then `summarize` accordingly, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>% 
      group_by(ID, start_time, End_time) %>% 
      summarise(Traffic = sum(Traffic))
```

Comment: Consider adding a bit of detail to your answer to make it work better as a standalone